# Jquery - html - Javascript - Atualizar campos da página ao cadastrar informação

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa noite

Inicialmente, agradeço desde já a atenção daqueles que de alguma forma me ajudarem.

Então, na verdade, eu nem sei como pesquisar isso no google, então, resolvi escrever aqui para ver se existe algo neste sentido.

A minha dúvida é o seguinte, por exemplo, eu tenho um sistema web que trabalha com janelas (http://jspanel.de/), e eu tenho a tela de cadastro de usuário e o cadastro de cidade.

Ao cadastrar uma nova cidade, eu queria que o campo cidade na janela de cadastro de usuários, atualizasse as cidades para receber essa nova incluída. Tá, eu sei, eu posso fazer isso manualmente ele atualizar e tals. Contudo a intenção não é essa. É ser algo automático.

Existe alguma biblioteca ou sei lá, alguma ideia para isso?

Obrigado

---

Então, complementando e respondedo as perguntas, sim, essas janelas são carregadas por ajax, mas cada uma faz a sua busca ao ser inicializada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS.: Na janela usuários eu não tenho o campo cidade ainda, pois eu estava pensando em como fazer...rsrsrs**

E por exemplo, se já tivesse o campo cidade na janela de usuários, ao abrir a página, no requisição do ajax eu já faria um select com as cidades cadastradas no banco.

Contudo o problema é depois dela já estar aberta. Pois o problema é o seguinte, agora eu só tenho a janela usuários aberta que precisa atualizar o campo cidade. Mas se futuramente eu abrir outra jenela que tbm possuí o campo cidade, aí ele não vai atualizar pq eu só programei na página de usuários para inserir uma cidade nova. rsrsrsrss

É meio pira, mas eu vi isso num sistema de rastreamento de veículos (traccar.org), em java, e ele também trabalhava com janela, e ao inserir um veículo, ele automaticamente já inseria aquele registro de veículo em todos os campos das outras janelas que tinham como opção a escolha de veículos.

Peço desculpas, eu tentei dar uma pesquisada em alguma coisa para ver se conseguia pensar em algo, mas o problema é que eu nem sei como jogar isso no google.

Para não dizer que eu não pensei em nada, saca só a ideia que eu tive. Eu pensei em colocar todos os campos cidade, de todas as janelas com o class='cidade_atualiza', e um script (javascript ou jquery), utilizando uma conexão socket. Aí, quando cadastrar uma nova cidade o próprio servidor vai me dar um retorno com esse nova registro adicionado, e eu pego esse registro novo e atualizo em todos os campos através do class='cidade_atualiza'. O que vocês acham? Foi uma ideia doida...rsrsrs

Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: como o campo cidade na janela de cadastro de usuários é mostrada? É um select? Coloca um trecho de código do formulário de cadastro, fica mais fácil pro pessoal ajudar

Comment: Olá, como você preenche hoje as cidades?
É uma requisição ajax?
Se for, é só você fazer uma nova chamada a função que carrega as cidades logo após incluir uma nova.

Comment: Podes juntar o HTML que tens e como estão a ser mostradas as cidades antes de juntar novas? Outra coisa, esse registo é feito no servidor também?

Comment: ta esclarecido acima!